# jquery passing array data to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a function to get the variable of onclick and pass it to the function, but I want it in different format:

```
$('.ajax').live('click', function() {   
    var Loading = 'Loading...';
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var container = '#myDivcontent';
    looadContents(url,Loading,container);
    return false;
});
```

and the function looks like :

```
looadContents(url,Loading,container) {
..
...
$(contaner).load(url);
...
..
}
```

I would like to have like array format or json data format when I call the function:

```
$('.ajax').live('click', function() {   
    looadContents({
             url : $(this).attr('href'),
             Loading : 'Loading...',
             container: '#myDivcontent'
     });
    return false;
});
```

Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: Just to check: Is `looadContents` supposed to be the same function as `ajaxModalLoad`?

Comment: You will have to explain this a little further

Comment: what data do you want in json format ?

Comment: Retagged [tag:JavaScript]; the question really has little to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass the information like an object, you can simply access it as one:

```
function looadContents(options) {
    $(options.container).load(options.url);
}

looadContents({ url: '...', container: '#...' });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use what's sometimes called an "options" object (what you refer to as "JSON data format" is simply a JavaScript object literal):

```
function loadContents(options) {
    var url = options.url;
    var Loading = options.Loading;
    /* etc. */
}
```

You can also leverage this approach to provide default values for certain parameters:

```
function loadContents(options) {
    var url = options.url || "http://default-url.com/",
    var Loading = options.Loading || "Loading...";
    var container = options.container || "#container";

    $(container).load(url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This syntax works as expected.

```
function display(obj)
{
    console.log(obj.name + " loves " + obj.love);
}
display({name:"Jared", love:"Jamie"});
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this possibly what you are looking for?

```
function looadContents(o) {

  alert(o.url);
  alert(o.container);

}

looadContents({ url:"abc", container: "def" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
looadContents(input) {
  //...
  $(input.contaner).load(input.url);
  //...
}
```